# Configure Spring mail sender dynamically

Tags: database, spring, email, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC App that needs to send email notification to registered users. As long as this app will be used by different admins in different environments I need to set configuration settings in the embedded database. My problem is that I've been reading Spring documentation and seem that these settings must be set in a xml file. So, is there any way to get this settings from the database and configure the mail sender (if necessary) every time I need to send an email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring EMail function is just a thin wrapper around java's standard mail function (javax.mail) https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/.

You do not need to use the spring mail function if you do not want, you can use java.mail directly. There it should be relative easily to use different configuration for every mail.

Comment: The configuration would be exactly the same but that is exactly what I was looking for. The admin must set the configuration after deployment and this could change in a future (use other smtp server for example). Thank you very much @Ralph.